# Uninstalled app still showing icon?

Tags: uninstall

I recently uninstalled live magic through the terminal, however there is still a live magic icon that cant be removed, help?

Comment: What is it? Where did you get it? How did you install it? Please provide enough info in your questions so that others can help you. You haven't provided enough information.

Answer (score 3):

Try first with `sudo apt-get autoremove`. This will remove the unnecessary dependencies.

Then in `/usr/share/applications` just delete the corresponding .desktop file for the uninstalled application. If you still see the icon on the launcher, just right click it and press unlock from launcher.